# LRU on database table (android)

Tags: android, database, realm, lru

I have a question about using the LRU algorithm on a database table. In a table with page objects I would like, when the Xth page is added, the least recently used page to be removed. I want to implement this somewhat efficiently. Note that the page rows are large, but not many. The max number of pages (X) in the database will be set at 30.

Bad solution: Adding a last_accessed field to the page table is not efficient: updating the row on every select (will copy the row under the surface?) will be overhead because the page row is large.

My proposed solution:

A. I will add a PageCache table with just one row: page_id.

B. I will add a PageManager java class that will be used on all access of the pages table, and will keep an in memory list of PageCache's pageIds (in memory to prevent updates on the PageCache table on EACH select statement). The rough overview of this class:

- onStart: get PageCache table from DB and load it into a LinkedList.
- onGet (of any page): set this page's id to the top of LinkedList.
- onAdd (of any page): check LinkedList size, too large = delete page at bottom of LinkedList (also in the page table).
- onStop: repopulate DB table with LinkedList.

We are using Realm on Android.

Drawback: I will need to route all Page-table access from my app to go through this PageManager class. Future programmers will need to know of this, when adding any get/add/update page calls.

I don't like this drawback, is there a better solution? Or any ways of improving the above?

Comment: Note that Realm uses zero-copy, so it is very low overhead in terms of Java heap space to query for objects. You will only ever load the fields that you actually access not the entire object.

Comment: Also, there is no way around keeping track of last accessed pages somewhere (in memory or Realm). In-memory will definitely be faster, but you also loose all guarantees of keeping properly track, e.g. what happens if the app crashes?

Comment: Good point. A crash is not normal flow, the LRU cash may be out of sync then, as long as nothing breaks. Solution: onStart of the PageManager,  after retrieving all items from the PageCache table, I will clear the PageCache table. If at the start of onStart, the retrieved items are empty, and the Page table is not, than I will know there must have been a crash (the onStop (saves changes in DB) was never called on my last instance = crash), and I will repopulate the PageCache randomly from the Page table for once to solve this.